# Join nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a result from `Q.all()` which is something like this -

```
promise = [Arr1,Arr2,Arr3....]
```

Each `Arr` can be either `null` or an array of plain JS objects.

I want to join all these arrays to one big array;

I can loop over and use array `concat` method to join them.

Is there any other elegant solution which is inbuilt in JS ?

Here is sample array -

```
    [
      {
        "endDate": "2015-06-11 14:52:00",
        "quantity": 75,
      },
      {
        "endDate": "2015-06-11 14:42:00",
        "quantity": 78,
      },
      {
        "endDate": "2015-06-01 14:43:00",
        "quantity": 69,
      },
      {
        "endDate": "2015-05-14 13:38:00",
        "quantity": 85,
      }
    ]
```

> I have these libraries available as well `lodash`, `angular`

Comment: Can you add sample array

Comment: Your sample is just **one** array, but your question says you have an array of them (e.g., nested arrays).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes its sample of one array. All the other array follow same structure

Comment: If you have a simple loop that does what you want, I would stick with it. I bet it will be more readable than the LoDash solutions that have been proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that would be a combination of [`flattenDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep) (to do the flattening) and [`without`](https://lodash.com/docs#without) (to remove `null`s — at least, I think you wanted to remove `null`s; if not, take `without` out):

```
var result = _.without(_.flattenDeep(yourArray), null);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
// NOTE: You said you had an array with arrays in it, so I've taken
// the one array you gave and used it as two entries in the array
// below (with some minor mods). Note also the nulls.
var yourArrays = [
    [
        {
            "endDate": "2015-06-11 14:52:00",
            "quantity": 75
        },
        {
            "endDate": "2015-06-11 14:42:00",
            "quantity": 78
        },
        {
            "endDate": "2015-06-01 14:43:00",
            "quantity": 69
        },
        {
            "endDate": "2015-05-14 13:38:00",
            "quantity": 85
        }
    ],
    null,
    null,
    [
        {
            "endDate": "2015-07-11 14:52:00",
            "quantity": 12
        },
        {
            "endDate": "2015-07-11 17:42:00",
            "quantity": 34
        },
        {
            "endDate": "2015-07-01 13:43:00",
            "quantity": 56
        },
        {
            "endDate": "2015-08-14 12:38:00",
            "quantity": 85
        }
    ]
];
var result = _.without(_.flattenDeep(yourArrays), null);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
"beforeend",
"<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + "</pre>"
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I prefer [compact()](https://lodash.com/docs#compact) over `without()` for removing _falsey_ values.

Comment: @AdamBoduch: I don't know he wants to remove all falsey values. :-) Actually, I'm not quite sure where I got the idea he wanted to remove `null`s, but I'm fairly sure he does...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Yes I actually wanted to remove `null`s thats why I mentioned there are possible `null` values as well. But without me explicitly mentioning you used `without()`.Great

Answer (score 0):

you cam simple use [`.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff679976(v=vs.94).aspx) function.

```
var promise = [[0,1],[2,3],[],[6,7]]
var combineArr = promise.map(function(value, index, array) {
    return array[index];
  });
alert(combineArr);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fv98aqh5/2/)